# StackOverFlowException when initializing array of Vector3's

Tags: c#, opentk

I've been trying to draw utah teapot with VBO and everytime when i run my program it throws StackOverFlowException in my Teapot class

My Teapot class:

```
public class Teapot
{
    Vector3[] teapot;
    int VBO_ID;
    public Teapot()
    {
        teapot = new Vector3[18960]
        {
            #region teapot vectors
            new Vector3(1.368074f, 2.435437f, -0.227403f),
            new Vector3(1.381968f, 2.400000f, -0.229712f),
            new Vector3(1.400000f, 2.400000f, 0.000000f),
            new Vector3(1.400000f, 2.400000f, 0.000000f),
            new Vector3(1.385925f, 2.435437f, 0.000000f),
            ...............
            #endregion
        };
        VBO_ID = GL.GenBuffer();
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VBO_ID);
        GL.BufferData<Vector3>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(Vector3.SizeInBytes * teapot.Length), teapot, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
    }

    public void DRAW_TEAPOT()
    {
        GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VBO_ID);
        GL.VertexPointer(3, VertexPointerType.Float, Vector3.SizeInBytes,0);
        GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles ,0, teapot.Length);
    }

}
```

Is there another way to store a 3D model inside my program?

Comment: Step 1: Comment out everything in your constructor. Exception should go away. Then create a vector with 1 element in it. Then VBO_ID, etc. One step at a time until the exception is thrown. Without a stack trace we can't see where exactly it happens.

Comment: It shows me that GL.BufferData<Vector3> is causing the exception after commenting out some of the vectors inside teapot array

Comment: Does anyone know why it's being caused? are there other ways i can draw my models?

Comment: Paste bin the full class, I'll take a look.

Comment: Sorry but i deleted the whole class to write an OBJ loader, But thanks for trying to help :)